# PGAdmin 4 Debugger not working ? on Windows 10 x64

Tags: windows, postgresql, debugging, pgadmin-4

I finally post a message on stack since I'm stuck on this for ages. I run on my dev machine a postgresql 11.6 instance with PG Admin 4 v4.17.

I just want to debug trigger functions with the debugger feature exposed on PGAdmin website. I did all the step for the configuration :
1. Changed value of shared_preload_libraries in postgresql.conf file by $libdir/plugin_debugger.dll
2. Restarted postgresql 11 instance service in Windows services window
3. Restarted PGAdmin 4 server
4. Added the pldbgapi extension on the DB I want to be able to debug

At the end I can see a set breakpoint menu such as :

[image: PGadmin debug menu broken]

But it doesn't look like the menu I can see on PGAdmin website.
When a breakpoint is hit, I can step forward the function line by line but no information is given about the code. For example in trigger function on updates, I would like to check the value of New and Old, but in my case nothing appears in debugger. Is this a normal behavior or is there something wrong with my configuration ?

Thank you for your help